# Un-referencing the [reference] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup-request

It only has 7 questions, but I can't imagine [reference](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/reference) is specific enough to be useful. I didn't want to just clear this out without asking others if it could be useful.

Comment: Useless. I'd remove it.